# Coin flipping probability after beginning imbalance

Tags: probability

If I am about to flip a coin one thousand times, probability says I should end up with 500/500. If I flip the first 10 and they all come up heads, probability would now say that the next 990 should be 495/495 (for those that realize the fallacy of The Gamblers Fallacy...). However that would equal a total of 505/495, which is different than the initial probability. In other words, if I would look the 1000 as a whole I would expect a total of 500/500, but if I look at it as two groups, 10 and 990, I should expect 505/495.
How would I explain this switch?

Comment: If you assume it is a fair coin then yes in expectation you would have 500 heads and 500 tails. If you have 10 tosses and then 990 tosses by linearity of expectation, it would still work out to 500 heads and 500 tails (in expectation). There is no switch in expectation.

Comment: In one case you are assuming the first ten flips were heads, in the other case you are not making any assumptions.

Comment: You are dealing with a [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) (*and conditional probabilities in general*).  $E[X\mid Y]\neq E[X]$ in most circumstances.  You seem to be making the mistake of assuming $E[X\mid Y]=E[X]$ where here $X$ is the random variable counting the total number of heads and $Y$ the event that the first flips were heads.  $X$ is very much dependent on $Y$ here, not independent.

Comment: You probably threw the other $1023$ combinations of HT before you threw 10H.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we toss a fair coin so $\mathbb{P}(H) = \mathbb{P}(T) = \frac{1}{2}$

Let $X$ be the number of heads in 1000 tosses. $\displaystyle X = \sum_{i=1}^{1000} \mathbb{1}_{(\text{toss i} = H)}$

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{1000} \mathbb{1}_{(\text{toss i} = H)}\right] = \sum_{i=1}^{1000}\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}_{(\text{toss i} = H)} \right] = \sum_{i=1}^{1000} \mathbb{P}(H) = \frac{1000}{2}=500.$$

From this we should be able to see if we do $10$ tosses and then $990$ tosses we still get expected value $500$.

Now, if we have the information the first $10$ tosses are all heads then we  want to calculate

$\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid \text{first 10 tosses are H}\right]$. Recall tosses of a coin are independent events so we get.

$$\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid \text{first 10 tosses are H}\right] = 10 +  \sum_{i=1}^{990}\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}_{(\text{toss i} = H)} \right]=10+\frac{990}{2}=505.$$

To take it a step further, lets say the first $m$ tosses are heads, for $0 \le m \le 1000$. Then we get

$$\mathbb{E}\left[X \mid \text{first $m$ tosses are H}\right] = m +  \sum_{i=1}^{1000-m}\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}_{(\text{toss i} = H)} \right]=m+\frac{1000-m}{2}=500+\frac{m}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

(Making this a community wiki since it was answered well in the comments.)

Conditioning on an event can, and should, change probabilities.

Example: If I roll a die, there's a $1/6$ chance that it lands on a 5. But if I'm given that the die roll was higher than 3, now there's a $1/3$ chance that it landed on 5. This isn't a "switch"; it's an incorporation of information into a probability computation. The same is happening in your example.